# Get the count of Model Required properties that filled

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, reflection

In my ASP.NET MVC application, I have created a model for customer details to be saved in the database.

When I retrieved the data from the database in the controller, I want to get out of the required field how many fields were filled.

How to get this done on the controller?

This is done for an existing database, I'm building a new project based on that database.

So when retrieving the data from the database and passing the data to the view, I want to pass that out of the required fields, and this count is filled.

I can assign the required fields to count to a property.

Other count is needed to know how to get it.

This is an example model

```
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; } 

[Required]
[DisplayName("Surname")]
public string Sur_Name { get; set; }

[Required]
[DisplayName("Name")]
public string Name { get; set; }

[Required]
[DisplayName("Citizenship")]
public int Citizen_Country_Id { get; set; }
```

I have tried this, want to know if the way is correct.

```
int countRequired = customer.GetType().GetProperties().Select(x=>x.GetValue(customer,null)).Count(c=>c ==null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use reflection for this, `GetRequiredProperties` will give you all required properties and their type as key-value pair. then you can run a loop and get the value for each property. for the value type default value should be 0 and for the reference type, it should be null. you can add the check accordingly. I have left some code for you to try and figure it out with he given information.

```
public static Dictionary<string, System.Type> GetRequiredProperties<T>()
{
    var info = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T))
        .Cast<PropertyDescriptor>()
        .Where(p => p.Attributes.Cast<Attribute>().Any(a => a.GetType() == typeof(RequiredAttribute)))
        .ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.PropertyType); 
    return info;
}

foreach (var item in prop)
{
    var value =  obj.GetType().GetProperty(item.Key).GetValue(obj, null);

    var type = item.Value;
}
```